# Cakephp 3 - Link objects from database

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm actually a website using CakePhP and I'm stuck with something I don't understand.

I have some events(e_pk_id, ...) and some tires(p_pk_id, ...), they are link by a table events_require_tires(pue_pk_fk_evenement_id,pue_pk_fk_pneu_id).

But when I want to get the object using EventsRequireTires' Controller, it returns me :

```
{
  "pneuUtilisableEvenements": []
}
```

For Events, here is its Table:

```
/**
 * Evenements Model
 *
 * @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $pneuUtilisableEvenements
```

And :

```
$this->belongsTo('pneuUtilisableEvenements', [
        'foreignKey' => 'e_pk_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

My tires :

```
@property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $pneuUtilisableEvenements
```

And:

```
$this->belongsTo('pneuUtilisableEvenements', [
        'foreignKey' => 'p_pk_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

And for my linking table :

```
* @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Evenements
* @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Pneus
```

With :

```
 $this->belongsTo('Evenements', [
        'foreignKey' => 'pue_pk_fk_evenement_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Pneus', [
        'foreignKey' => 'pue_pk_fk_pneu_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

Do you have any idea guy ? ~

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to achieve is a so called "BelongsToMany" association.

Read more in the CakePHP docs: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongstomany-associations

---

BTW: Your table and key names seem kind of hard to read. Maybe this could be optimized by following the CakePHP Conventions.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html

Comment: Thank you for your help ~ Yeah I will check more about the conventions ! 
I figured out that all my tables were using the MyIsam Engine ... and now I put back to InnoDb, everything is fine.

I'm just pissed by the fact it didn't remove the field that helps to link the 2 objects ~

Like a table Users(id_users, house_fk_users) and the table Houses(id_houses, label_houses), will return if I use view() or index() in Users.
{
    "id_users":1,
    "houses_fk_users":1,
    "houses":[
        "id_houses":1,
        "label_houses":"Bla"
    ]
}
Any idea to remove "houses_fk_users":1 ?

Comment: Why should the key be removed? If you don't want the key in your result set like so: `$arr = $entity->toArray(); unset($arr['Model']['field']);` (untested pseudo code)

Comment: Thank you for your help ~ I don't know, I just don't like to see this